# Changes in a viewmodel property is not being reflected in the UI

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new in WPF I have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. I have one viewmodel containing the property "TeamMemberList". The control executes the setter part, changes the property value but the PropertyChanged event remains null.
Here is code:

ViewModelBase:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }        
}
```

ViewModel:(Which inherits the viewmodelbase)
Property is

```
    public List<Employee> TeamMemberList
    {
        get
        {
            return _teamMemberList;
        }
        set
        {
            _teamMemberList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TeamMemberList");
        }
    }
```

Binding

```
<ListBox Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding TeamMemberList, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
```

when new employee added to the DB, model reads it & creates List for all emplyee then the TeamMeberList property gets updated. This is updation method for TeamMemberList

```
    var qryEmp = from employee in ClientModel.EmployeeList
                         where employee.ReportingManager == UserProfile.EmployeeId
                         select new Employee
                         {
                             EmployeeId = employee.EmployeeId,
                             EmployeeName = employee.EmployeeName,
                             Designation = employee.Designation,
                             ProfilePic = employee.ProfilePic,
                         };
            TeamMemberList = qryEmp.ToList();
```

And implementation of Employee

```
public class Employee : ViewModelBase
{

    private string _employeeName;
    private string _employeeId;
    private string _profilePic;
    private string _designation;
    private string _reportinManager;

    public string EmployeeName
    {
        get
        {
            return _employeeName;
        }
        set
        {

            _employeeName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("EmployeeName");
        }

    }


    public string EmployeeId
    {
        get
        {
            return _employeeId;
        }
        set
        {
            _employeeId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("EmployeeId");
        }
    }


    public string ProfilePic
    {
        get
        {
            return _profilePic;
        }
        set
        {
            _profilePic = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProfilePic");
        }
    }


    public string Designation
    {
        get
        {
            return _designation;
        }
        set
        {
            _designation = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Designation");
        }
    }
    public string ReportingManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _reportinManager;
        }
        set
        {
            _reportinManager = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ReportingManager");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That will be null unless you assign a delegate to that.. Its not a problem for update the binding.. Show the code where your are updating and also the implementation of your Model(Employee Class).

Comment: @Sankarann - `That will be null unless you assign a delegate to that` - This is not true. What do you meant by this?

Comment: @user3217737 - Are you setting Viewmodel as DataContext to your View?

Comment: @RohitVats: For the update of Binding, Its not required to have a value and for internal use of handling the property changed that `PropertyChanged` can be assigned with a delegate.

Comment: But OP wanted it for binding purpose only. So, no need of assigning delegate.

Comment: @RohitVats: Yes I have set datacontex to view, infact initially when application is loaded the list showing the previously added employee but when I am adding new employee the list is not get updated

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what the problem is when we don't see more code (eg: how you are setting the DataContext etc...).

But there is an easy way to debug your bindings by adding the following attribute to it:

```
<ListBox Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding TeamMemberList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
         PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High>
```

Adding this attribute will output the whole binding sequence to the Output window of Visual Studio. That should point out what is going wrong.

If you want to enable this for *all* bindings, you can also use the Visual Studio options:

[image: Visual Studio Options dialog to enable WPF Tracing]

Answer (score 0):

Use ObserveableCollection instead of a list

Comment: While a List won't allow as rich interactions as an ObservableCollection, it should still work, so I don't think this is the solution